# Converting a delimited file into a Tree

Tags: java, list, sorting, treeset, delimited

I'm working on converting a delimited file into an ordered tree structure. Below is a sample input...

```
1.2.3.4.5
1.3.2.4.5
1.2.4.5.6
```

I need to be able to convert this into an output like the following (in a searchable tree structure)...

```
1
-2
--3
---4
----5
--4
---5
----6
-3
--2
---4
----5
```

My thoughts on a solution to this was to...

1. Iterate the text file and create an arraylist that represents each row
2. Use Collections.sort() to make the arraylist sorted
3. Use a TreeMap to store the "base" record as a key (1 in this case) and an arrayList of strings to contain all the records
4. Iterate the TreeMap's keys and convert its arrayList to a LinkedHashSet that contains Nodes that represent each entry
5. Iterate the Tree's keys and print each node buy its index value

I thought everything was working well but when I started testing this approach, I found my output looks like below...

```
1
-2
--3
---4
----5
--4
---5
----6
-3
--2
```

As can be seen, the Nodes under 3/2/xx are not present, this is due to the logic I am using to build the LinkedHashSet for my Node values (Node(3, 4)) will simply be ignore because its a duplicate Node. I thought I was going in the right direction with this but now I can see my logic is clearly flawed. Does anyone have any suggestions for an approach for something like this? My current code is below...

**TreeBuilder.java**

```
public class TreeBuilder {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Get a list of records
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("1.2.3.4.5");
    data.add("1.3.2.4.5");
    data.add("1.2.4.5.6");

    Collections.sort(data);

    // Build the "Base" tree
    TreeMap<String, List<String>> tree = buildBaseTree(data);

    // Build the target tree structure
    TreeMap<String, LinkedHashSet<Node>> finalTree = convertListToSet(tree);

    printRecords(finalTree);

 }

 public static void printRecords(
        TreeMap<String, LinkedHashSet<Node>> recordTree) {

    System.out.println("---------Records---------");

    for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedHashSet<Node>> entry : recordTree
            .entrySet()) {

        System.out.println(entry.getKey());

        // Print out the structured data
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Node> iterator = entry.getValue().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            Node node = iterator.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < node.index; i++) {
                stringBuilder.append("-");
            }

            System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString() + node.value);

            // "reset" the builder
            stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        }
    }

 }

 private static TreeMap<String, LinkedHashSet<Node>> convertListToSet(
        TreeMap<String, List<String>> tree) {

    TreeMap<String, LinkedHashSet<Node>> finalMap = new TreeMap<String, LinkedHashSet<Node>>();
    LinkedHashSet<Node> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<Node>();

    // Iterate the entry set
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : tree.entrySet()) {

        List<String> records = entry.getValue();
        for (String record : records) {
            String[] recordArray = record.split("\\.");

            for (int i = 1; i < recordArray.length; i++) {
                Node node = new Node(i, Integer.parseInt(recordArray[i]));
                linkedHashSet.add(node);
            }
        }

        finalMap.put(entry.getKey(), linkedHashSet);

        // reset our linkedHashSet
        linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<Node>();

    }

    System.out.println("Final map " + finalMap);

    return finalMap;
 }

 /**
  * Builds a tree with base record keys and a list of records for each key.
  * 
  * @param data
  * @return
  */
 private static TreeMap<String, List<String>> buildBaseTree(List<String> data) {

    TreeMap<String, List<String>> tree = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> recordList = null;

    // First find all base records
    for (String record : data) {

        String[] baseEntry = record.split("\\.");
        if (!tree.containsKey(baseEntry[0])) {
            recordList = new ArrayList<String>();
            tree.put(baseEntry[0], recordList);
        }
    }

    // Now place all sub-records in each base record
    for (String record : data) {

        String[] baseEntry = record.split("\\.");
        tree.get(baseEntry[0]).add(record);
    }

    System.out.println("------------------Base Tree---------------");
    System.out.println(tree);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");

    return tree;
 }

 private static List<String> readData(String file) {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Get a list of all the records
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            data.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Sort the list so its ordered
    System.out.println("-------------Sorted Data Set-----------");
    Collections.sort(data);
    for (String record : data) {
        System.out.println(record);
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

    return data;
 }
}
```

**Node.java**

```
public class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

 int index;
 int value;

 public Node(int index, int value) {
    this.index = index;
    this.value = value;
 }

 public int getIndex() {
    return index;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return "Node [index=" + index + ", value=" + value + "]";
 }

 public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
 }

 public int getValue() {
    return value;
 }

 public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
 }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(Node o) {

    Node otherNode = (Node) o;

    if (this.index > otherNode.index)
        return 1;

    if (this.index < otherNode.index) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + index;
    result = prime * result + value;
    return result;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Node other = (Node) obj;
    if (index != other.index)
        return false;
    if (value != other.value)
        return false;
    return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: I can't quite work out your requirements. Is the tree supposed to consider the list as ordered and use a common node structure for lists that start with common attributes? If so you can't sort the lists before inserting as the existing order is significant. I'll add an answer on the assumption that these are your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be complicated. All you need is a `SortedMap` of `SortedMap` instances and there's only one trick to it: Parameterizing it recursively for type safety (if desired).

```
package com.acme;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        rows.add("1.2.3.4.5");
        rows.add("1.3.2.4.5");
        rows.add("1.2.4.5.6");

        MyTreeMap root = new MyTreeMap();
        for (String row : rows) {
            MyTreeMap n = root;
            String[] cells = row.split("\\.");
            for (String cell : cells) {
                MyTreeMap child = n.get(cell);
                if (child == null) {
                    n.put(cell, child = new MyTreeMap());
                }
                n = child;
            }
        }

        print(root, "", "-");
    }

    static void print(MyTreeMap m, String indentationStr, String indentationStrAddition) {
        for (Entry<String, MyTreeMap> o : m.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(indentationStr + o.getKey());
            print(o.getValue(), indentationStr + indentationStrAddition, indentationStrAddition);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is just a construct that helps us to parameterize recursively.
     */
    static class MyTreeMap extends TreeMap<String, MyTreeMap> {private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, this is exactly what I was looking for. It took me a few read-throughs to understand whats going on here but for anyone else that finds it confusing, the approach that Brian provided is very much like building a binary tree. The concept is basically start at the root for each and every column from the input data, traverse the current tree, if a branch doesn't have a child, add it. Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you want to create search trees from a list of integers that share common prefixes. If that's the case then I think you can achieve this with a lot less code:

```
private static class TreeNode {

    private final Map<Integer, TreeNode> children = new HashMap<>();

    public void insert(List<Integer> values) {
        if (!values.isEmpty()) {
            children.putIfAbsent(values.get(0), new TreeNode());
            children.get(values.get(0)).insert(values.subList(1, values.size()));
        }
    }

    public void print(int level) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, TreeNode> entry : children.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(level, "-")));
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            entry.getValue().print(level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not certain if you intend to sort the list of integers. If so you can add a `Collections.sort` at the appropriate place in the code.